# Ruby collection out of order

Tags: ruby

I have the following:

```
BB_AREAS = {
  :about          => {:link => "quem somos", :slug => "quem-somos"},
  :expositors     => {:link => "expositores",:slug => "expositores"},
  :map            => {:link => "planta", :slug => "planta"},
  :activities     => {:link => "atividades",:slug => "atividades"},
  :address        => {:link => "como chegar",:slug => "como-chegar"},
  :support        => {:link => "apoio", :slug => "apoio"},
  :optin          => {:link => "cadastro",:slug => "cadastro"},
  :how_expositors => {:link => "como expor",:slug => "como-expor"},
  :press          => {:link => "imprensa",:slug => "imprensa"},
  :contact        => {:link => "contato",:slug => "contato"},
}

BB_MENU_AREAS       = BB_AREAS.each_with_object({}) { |(k, v), h| h[k] = v[:link]}
BB_MENU_AREAS_SLUG  = BB_AREAS.each_with_object({}) { |(k, v), h| h[k] = v[:slug]}
```

And in the view I have the following:

```
=render :partial => '/shared/menu', :collection => BB_MENU_AREAS.map {|link, menu| {:link => link, :menu => menu}}, :spacer_template => '/shared/menu_separator'
```

I want the menu to render in the same order of BB_AREAS, but it is rendered in an arbitrary order.

Comment: maps are unordered data structures

Comment: What version of Ruby are you using? In 1.9+ maps are ordered by insertion, in 1.8 they're not.

Answer (score 3):

Hashes are ordered by insertion order in Ruby 1.9+, otherwise they have an internal order.

IMO this data belongs in an array of actual objects, though; roughly:

```
class Area
  attr_accessor :name, :link, :slug
  def initialize(name, link, slug)
    @name = name
    @link = link
    @slug = slig
  end
end

BB_AREAS = [
  Area.new("About", "quem somos", "quem-somos"),
  Area.new("Expositors", "expositores", "expositores"),
  # etc.
]
```

If you *actually* need to extract individual components in order you may.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby Hashs are orderless in Ruby 1.8 and lower. However, in Ruby 1.9 and higher, Hashes are ordered. There is a backward compatible solution though:

```
BB_AREAS = [
  [:about          , {:link => "quem somos", :slug => "quem-somos"}],
  [:expositors     , {:link => "expositores",:slug => "expositores"}],
  [:map            , {:link => "planta", :slug => "planta"}],
  [:activities     , {:link => "atividades",:slug => "atividades"}],
  [:address        , {:link => "como chegar",:slug => "como-chegar"}],
  [:support        , {:link => "apoio", :slug => "apoio"}],
  [:optin          , {:link => "cadastro",:slug => "cadastro"}],
  [:how_expositors , {:link => "como expor",:slug => "como-expor"}],
  [:press          , {:link => "imprensa",:slug => "imprensa"}],
  [:contact        , {:link => "contato",:slug => "contato"}],
]
BB_MENU_AREAS       = BB_AREAS.each_with_object({}) { |(k, v), h| h[k] = v[:link]}
BB_MENU_AREAS_SLUG  = BB_AREAS.each_with_object({}) { |(k, v), h| h[k] = v[:slug]}
```

Nothing do change in your view. Additionally, in this data structure, instead of `[key]`, you need to use `.assoc(key)[1]`.